# Vue Cli Error: Rule can only have one resource source (provided resource and test + include + exclude)

Tags: vue.js, npm, webpack, vue-cli-4, webpack-config

Npm run serve is not working after I freshly installed npm in the project folder. I am using the latest webpack. Also tried uninstalling and installing npm gloabally. Though this was running before npm install. Nothing has changes in package.json since begining. I don't have idea whats going wrong here. Gives error below

at checkResourceSource (E:\projects\project-emr\emr\node_modules@vue\cli-service\node_modules\webpack\lib\RuleSet.js:167:11)

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.11.2",
    "@toast-ui/vue-calendar": "^1.1.1",
    "animate.css": "^3.7.2",
    "auth0-js": "^9.12.2",
    "autoprefixer": "latest",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.1.0",
    "cache-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "classnames": "2.2.6",
    "core-js": "^3.3.2",
    "css-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "highcharts": "^8.0.0",
    "highcharts-vue": "^1.3.5",
    "instantsearch.css": "^7.3.1",
    "instantsearch.js": "^3.6.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
    "lodash": "latest",
    "lottie-web": "^5.5.10",
    "material-design-icons-iconfont": "^6.1.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "node-snackbar": "^0.1.16",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "ramda": "^0.26.1",
    "register-service-worker": "^1.6.2",
    "smooth-scrollbar": "^8.5.1",
    "swiper": "^5.3.0",
    "url-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "vee-validate": "^3.2.2",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-class-component": "^7.2.3",
    "vue-file-agent": "^1.7.3",
    "vue-flatpickr-component": "^8.1.5",
    "vue-form-wizard": "^0.8.4",
    "vue-i18n": "^8.15.3",
    "vue-instantsearch": "^2.6.0",
    "vue-morris": "^1.1.0",
    "vue-photo-grid": "^1.0.2",
    "vue-property-decorator": "^8.3.0",
    "vue-resource": "^1.5.1",
    "vue-router": "^3.1.3",
    "vue-select": "^3.4.0",
    "vue-slick": "^1.1.15",
    "vue-slider-component": "3.0.32",
    "vuedraggable": "^2.23.2",
    "vuefire": "^2.2.1",
    "vuetify": "^2.3.10",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1",
    "webpack": "latest",
    "wowjs": "^1.1.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.7.0",
    "@fullcalendar/list": "^4.3.0",
    "@mdi/font": "^5.6.55",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.1.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.1.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-pwa": "^4.1.2",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "^4.1.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "^4.1.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.1.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-standard": "^4.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
    "less": "^3.10.3",
    "less-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "lint-staged": "^9.5.0",
    "mutationobserver-shim": "^0.3.3",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.0",
    "portal-vue": "^2.1.6",
    "sass": "^1.19.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "stylus": "^0.54.7",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.2",
    "vue-cli-plugin-bootstrap-vue": "^0.6.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-i18n": "~0.6.1",
    "vue-clipboard2": "^0.3.1",
    "vue-loader": "^15.7.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
  }
```

Comment: `rm -r .node_modules package-lock.json && npm install`

Comment: Tried this but still doesn't work. I think this is the issue with webpack configuration. Below is Error Error: Rule can only have one resource source (provided resource and test + include + exclude)

Comment: I am stuck here..

Comment: It is solved. I have reverted package-lock.json file to the previous version and then did npm install. Added required new packages one by one and  It Worked!!!